# render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template_name'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The following screenshot contains the code of my `views.py` code:

[image: screenshot]

I am getting the error:

```py
render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template_name'
```

while running the `url` from `pycharm`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Don't post images of code.

Answer (score 17):

First argument of render() is missing, update it like this :

```
return render (request,'blabla.html')
```

Comment: Thanks Ines Tilli

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I got cross eyed and forget the to type "request".

Answer (score 0):

Look at your django settings.py "TEMPLATES" DIRS configure is ok.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: check out this screenshot]

you can use either render(request, "template_name")
or redirect('/template_name/')
i've used redirect('/') to redirect to the same page